# Disable WoW64 Redirection

Tags: vbscript, wow64

I can't found a solution for this problem.

I need to be able to launch cmd.exe **64bit** from a **32bit** VBScript.
I was thinking that exists something like the [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx) from Windows API, but I can't find anything for VBS.

There is a method to can achieve this?
In previous versions of Windows this can be achieved using the *Sysnative* directory, but on Windows 10 is no longer available...

Thank you all!

Comment: If you find the solution by yourself you may answer your own question. This is better than putting it in *edit*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved, I was mistaken when I said that SysNative doesn't exists on Windows 10, I wasn't able to *physically* see this folder, but when used through code **works perfectly**!

My mistake.